# Using generics in interfaces, repeating the method

Tags: java, generics

I'm reading the article in the Internet and I don't get why in the `NextSomething` interface the `getAll()` method is written again. As I extends it with `Something<SomeClass>`, won't generics automatically put there a `SomeClass` instead of T? Is there any point to write `getAll()` method again, just with the existing class?

```
public interface Something <T> {

    //some methods
    List<T> getAll();
}

public interface NextSomething extends Something<SomeClass> {
    List<SomeClass> getAll();
}
```

Comment: You could rephrase this question title to make it a bit clearer. Interesting question though.

Comment: I think you don't need to define getAll() in child interface.

Comment: Indeed, you do not need to redeclare the method in interface `NextSomething`, you can just leave it out. Any class that implements the interface, does ofcourse have to implement the method with the appropriate type arguments.

Comment: What's the article?

Comment: @BenGreen To specify, it was te tutorial with that kind of example and I was wondering if there is point to repeat it.

Comment: @Kubekk I would say that this wasn't worth doing, unless you wanted to specifically add any additional javadoc to the `NextSomething` interface or something like that. I imagine the example was just to explicitly show what having in generics in interfaces can be used for.

Comment: @BenGreen I'm still learning and I'm trying to get known as many "tricky" things in Java as possible. In the example there was some more methods and just this one was repeated. (The whole example was about the Abstract factory pattern and the 'Something' interface was the base).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's really no point in redefining it.